# XmlSchema has no elements (C#)

Tags: c#, xsd

I load an XmlSchema from a file and it has other schema in its schema.Includes.

For this included XmlSchema, the Elements and SchemaTypes properties are in length 0. However they should contain some element/types according to the actual schema. This included XmlSchema does have the elements and complex types in its Items property, so why not in the normal properties? The primary schema has everything ok.

Comment: Please post some code from your schemas.

Answer (score -2):

when you create xmldocument object,you can set namespace uri and prefix by CreateDefaultAttribute()
after that,you can set some attributes by XmlElement.SetAttribute()
but the method cannot set some attributes related to some protocol or namespace